# Start python script from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, http

I'm trying to start a python script that will parse a csv file uploaded from the UI by the user.  On the client side, how do I make a call to start the python script (I've read AJAX http requests work)?  And then secondly, how do I take the user input (just a simple user upload with the  HTML tag) which will be read by the python script?

The back end python script works perfectly through the command line, I just need to create a front end for easier use.

Comment: So you want the user to run a python script locally on their machine through the browser? That's not possible.

Comment: no everything will be hosted on a single server.  I want the user to be able to start the python script using a UI

Comment: Use CGI, or fastGCI, or nodeJS, or PHP or something similar on the server to respond to the Ajax request.

Comment: why don't you try to use microframework such as [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)? You definitely can import your existing script and invoke the functions inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

Many (if not all) server side technology can solve your problem: CGI, Java Servlet, NodeJS, Python, PHP etc.

The steps are:

1. In browser, upload file via AJAX request.
2. In server, receive file sent from browser, save it somewhere in server disk.
3. After file is saved, invoke your python script to handle the file.

As your current script is written by Python, I guess Python is the best choice for server side technology.